# After "cordova run ios" terminal does not echo keyboard input

Tags: ios, macos, cordova

Using Cordova 4.1.2.  After successfully running the project on an iPad using:

```
cordova run ios
```

and exiting LLDB using `kill` or `safequit` commands the terminal window will no longer echo keyboard input.

Is there a shell command I can enter to restore normal function of the terminal window?  Currently I have to exit the terminal and start a new one after testing my cordova application.

Comment: What is your LLDB version? Is the command prompt shown still after exiting? Does it accept the commands even though it doesn't echo them?

Comment: LLDB version shows as: lldb-320.4.156
The command prompt is shown, keyboard input is not shown. It will accept and process what I type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that one of the scripts being run by the `cordova run ios` is turning off terminal echo.  Terminal settings before:

```
~>stty
speed 9600 baud;
lflags: echoe echoke echoctl pendin
iflags: iutf8
oflags: -oxtabs
cflags: cs8 -parenb
```

And after:

```
speed 9600 baud;
lflags: -icanon -iexten -echo echoe echoke echoctl
iflags: inlcr iutf8
oflags: -oxtabs
cflags: cs8 -parenb
dsusp   eof     lnext   reprint status  werase
<undef> <undef> <undef> <undef> <undef> <undef>
```

I have been able to work around this issue by carefully typing the following after LLDB exits to restore keyboard echo:

```
stty echo
```